# Movesense: is it possible to obtain data from multiple sensors

Tags: android, movesense

I am working on the development of an app to work with the [movesense](/questions/tagged/movesense) sensor.
Is it possible to stream the data from multiple devices to one Android device simultaneously?

Kind regards,

Sander

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible.

Please fetch source code from Movesense repository and there is Multi Connection example.

In short :
You are just doing 2 connections and 2 subscriptions on different devices. The same way like with single Movesense.

Comment: Great. I just figured out that it is in the new app. Thank you very much for the example.

Comment: I had a look at the sample activity for single connection and then for multi connection, why is the connection build up so vastly different? When using the connection approach like in the wiki tutorial, the RxBleClient is used to scan... In the MultiConnectionActivity in the sampleApp the connection is done with a custom MdsRx class... Could you elaborate on how and which way is the correct one?

Comment: There is ConnectivityAPI now so You are just using api.

Comment: I have edited the multi-connection example to connect to 3 movesense devices. But I am unable to connect to 3. It connects to two sensors, but then fails to connect to the third one. Can you tell me why this might be happening?

Comment: Where can I find this example, and what is the name of the file? I don't find it in the Movesense repository. Thank you

Comment: @JorgeJiménez Probably this is official repo https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/src